# How to use page controllers in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an application in which I have to use page controllers (Similar to the page controllers in iphone ). I could not find any such thing in android .
Is it possible to use this in android or any alternative of this in android  ...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no page controllers in Android API. But you can still use this design approach in you code I think. Just move all view interaction logic in separate controller class, leave in Activity derived class only activity specific code, like menu inflation etc.

Comment: Can you post some code or few links to explain in a better way. Actually what I want is to show pageController to show gallery images similar to iphone.